# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength') when uploading image to Firebase Storage

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an image to Firebase Storage using a Node.js backend and encountering:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength').

Here is my code:

**firebase.js**:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Firebase Storage
export const storage = getStorage(app);
```

**function file**:

```
import { storage } from "../auth/firebase.js";
import { ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage"; 
import fs from "fs"; 

// Add a function to upload an image to Firebase Storage
export const uploadImageToStorage = async (file) => {
  try {
    const storageRef = ref(storage, "uploads/" + file.filename);
    console.log("API:", file);

     // Create a ReadStream from the file data
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);

    // Upload the file using the uploadBytes
    const snapshot = await uploadBytes(storageRef, fileStream);

    // Get the download URL for the uploaded image
    const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);

    return downloadURL;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Image upload error:", error);
    return null;
  }
};
```

**route file**:

```
router.post(
  "/uploadDocument",
  AdminAuth,
  upload.single("image"),
  uploadDocument
);
```

**controller**:

```
export const uploadDocument = async (req, res) => {
  const { Document, Title } = req.body;

  let image = req.file;

  const imageUrl = await uploadImageToStorage(image);

  console.log(imageUrl);
  res.status(200).json({ msg: "upload" });
  return;

  //rest of code 
};
```

***Error :***

```
API: {
  fieldname: 'image',
  originalname: 'Screenshot from 2023-07-17 16-43-00.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  destination: 'uploads/',
  filename: 'cb103604b20db25ebfc3466c9c5be858',
  path: 'uploads/cb103604b20db25ebfc3466c9c5be858',
  size: 49874,
  byteLength: 49874
}
Image upload error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength')
    at file:///home/vishal7im/Tech/GBN/GBN-Backend/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/node-esm/index.node.esm.js:1257:38
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at FbsBlob.getBlob (file:///home/vishal7im/Tech/GBN/GBN-Backend/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/node-esm/index.node.esm.js:1256:25)
    at multipartUpload (file:///home/vishal7im/Tech/GBN/GBN-Backend/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/node-esm/index.node.esm.js:1818:26)
    at uploadBytes$1 (file:///home/vishal7im/Tech/GBN/GBN-Backend/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/node-esm/index.node.esm.js:2949:25)
    at uploadBytes (file:///home/vishal7im/Tech/GBN/GBN-Backend/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/node-esm/index.node.esm.js:3450:12)
    at uploadImageToStorage (file:///home/vishal7im/Tech/GBN/GBN-Backend/firebase/firestore/functions.js:9:28)
    at uploadDocument (file:///home/vishal7im/Tech/GBN/GBN-Backend/controllers/admin.js:210:26)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/vishal7im/Tech/GBN/GBN-Backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/vishal7im/Tech/GBN/GBN-Backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
```

i will try lots of approch

like I convert file into blob

```
/ Function to convert file data to Blob
const dataURItoBlob = (dataURI) => {
  const byteString = atob(dataURI.split(",")[1]);
  const mimeString = dataURI.split(",")[0].split(":")[1].split(";")[0];

  const ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
  const ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
  for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  return new Blob([ab], { type: mimeString });
};
```

and lots of approaches

Comment: Can you see if `fs.createReadStream` is returning a valid object? Or perhaps call `uploadBytes` on the `file` directly?